Expo iOS Universal Links valid but not opening application
I am in the process of implementing some Universal Links into my Expo project so my forgot password flow will still work on both the mobile application and PWA that I have built. I have verified that my apple-app-site-association file is correctly set up but leveraging Apple's Developer tool within iOS as well as using Branch.io to verify if there are any issues. This includes permissions, mime/content-type, etc. That being said, any links that I attempt to open from an email or Chrome still revert to the http requests within Chrome. Admittedly I am at somewhat of a loss here.
Considering the validation that I have already done, makes me think it could be some sort of path/regex issue, but at this point, who knows.
Here is what I have. It is worth noting that I do not have any handlers in the application as I am attempting to leverage the Expo router.
url to open
https://staging.app.cultivateprm.com/reset-password?token=asdfasd84654s6d5f4

apple-app-site-association
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "******.com.*****.cultivate"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/reset-password",
                        "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with reset-password."
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/login",
                        "comment": "Matches login."
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/*",
                        "comment": "Matches any other URL."
                    }
                ],
                "paths": [
                    "/",
                    "/reset-password",
                    "/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "******.com.*****.cultivate"
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "******.com.*****.cultivate"
        ]
    }
}

entitlements
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
      <string>applinks:staging.app.cultivateprm.com</string>
      <string>applinks:app.cultivateprm.com</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>

Update
I have played around with this a little more and it appears that everything works as expected IF you click the "Open" button in the upper right corner of your screen. However the application still does not open.


Universal links don't work in browsers other than safari on iOS.

That makes sense, however I am still getting the same behavior when opening the link from an email.

You can check with the universal link checker under the developer settings on the device, but you will also need to ensure that your app delegate handles the incoming universal link; I don't know what you need to do in expo for this.

I have verified each domain with the universal link checker within the developer settings and both have come back green. I will need to verify the AppDelegate's configuration.

@Paulw11 The application does not open at all (which is the problem I am having), so if that is the case, the app delegate and route handling would not matter correct?

If the developer settings says that the link is directed to your app then iOS is attempting to open your app.  If the app doesn't handle the incoming link then iOS will automatically open the link in the browser, so yes, you need code in your app or the link will not open in it.

I have tested the application in its current configuration with the following testing method: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#testing-urls (npx uri-scheme open https://staging.app.cultivateprm.com/reset-password --ios) and the application behaves as intended. I am going to mark this as resolved for now. Thanks @Paulw11
